# Predicate with Reflection in java

Tags: java, java-8

```
class DataObject
{
String attr1;
String attr2;
String attr3;

// getters of three fields(getAttr1(),getAttr2() and getAttr3())
// setters of three fields(setAttr1(),setAttr2() and setAttr3())
}   

     List<DataObject> result = null;//Output List of objects of 'DataObject' class

    List<DataObject> dataObjectList; // Input List of objects of 'DataObject'class. 
Predicate<DataObject>  first= e -> e.getAttr1().equals("Value1_1");
result = dataObjectList.stream().filter(first).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to filter my list of objects based on the conditions at runtime(Here condition is attr1 = "Value1_1").  My problem is that I will get the method name only in run time(It can be getAttr1() or getAttr2() or getAttr3() or any other function). I used reflection to solve this scenario.

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.example.java.DataObject");        
Class<?> noparams[] = {};
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getAttr1", noparams);
Predicate<DataObject>  first= e -> method.equals("Value1_1");
```

But the code will not give the required result. Please correct my code on reflection. Also please give me any alternative solutions.

Comment: All I see in your example is the constant string `"getAttr1"`.  Please be clearer about how you are getting the method name at runtime--and, most importantly, _when_.  Do you want the method name to be there before the predicate is created, or do you want to create a predicate that gets the method name when the predicate is applied?

Comment: I will get the methodname as a string at runtime.

Comment: The code will be                                                                                        String s="getAttr1";
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(s, noparams);

Comment: Why do have class name and method name as string? What is the core problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to use this predicate in streams. By streams I can filter this.

Comment: Read this -> [What is XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please look at the question and ask me any doubts

Answer (score 3):

You've to actually invoke the method to get the result back using [`Method#invoke()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) method. Right now, you're just comparing the `Method` object. Change that to:

```
Predicate<DataObject>  first= e -> method.invoke(e).equals("Value1_1");
```

But that's really a weird way. I'm sure there can be some other way, if you can show what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm getting error while doing this. Here I will get the name of the method in runtime. `String s="getAttr1"; Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(s, noparams);`

Comment: @DeepakShajan And what is the error? You'll have to handle some exceptions as always when you use reflection.

Comment: I'm doing in eclipse IDE. IDE want to surround with try/catch. But when adding try/catch, yet the error is not removed. Still IDE want to surround with try/catch.

Comment: @DeepakShajan Yes, you've to handle multiple exceptions. Can't you just go to the Java doc and see what all exceptions needs to be handled. These are basic stuffs, which you should know, before you start using stuffs like reflection.

Comment: I added try/catch many times and error is still there.

Answer (score 3):

Are you dead-set on doing this with reflection?  Reflection is often more trouble than it's worth.  How about this:

```
class DataObject {
    static enum Attr {
        Attr1(DataObject::getAttr1),
        Attr2(DataObject::getAttr2),
        Attr3(DataObject::getAttr3),
        Attr4(DataObject::getAttr4);

        final Function<DataObject, Object> getter;

        Attr(Function<DataObject, Object> getter) {
            this.getter = requireNonNull(getter);
        }
    }

    // .... rest of the class ....

}


Attr attribute = Attr.valueOf("Attr1");

List<DataObject> filtered = dataObjectList.stream()
        .filter(e -> "Value_1".equals(attribute.getter.apply(e)))
        .collect(toList());
```

Obviously, the downside is that you would have to add an enum value for every attribute.  But the upside is simplicity and the ability to refer to your attributes by type-safe enum rather than by strings.  It will also be very easy to get a list of valid attributes (`Attr.values()`).

Once you set that up, you can do fun things like adding the following to your `enum`:

```
<T> Predicate<DataObject> matches(Predicate<T> p) {
    return e -> p.test((T)getter.apply(e));
}
```

And then you'll be able to write your code like this:

```
Attr attribute = Attr.valueOf("Attr1");

List<DataObject> filtered = dataObjectList.stream()
        .filter(attribute.matches("Value_1"::equals))
        .collect(toList());
```